# Populate column based on other column values in Pandas

Tags: pandas, string, lambda

I am trying to populate the field "Result" based on fields F1, F2, F3 and F4. Based on which field has the value (other than "-" or "#"), that value needs to be extracted and put in "Result"

[image]

```
def fill_values(row):
 if (str(row['F1']) != '-' & str(row['F1']) != '#'):
    return str(row['F1'])
 elif (str(row['F2'] != '-') & str(row['F2'] != '#')):
    return str(row['F2'])
 elif (str(row['F3'] != '-') & str(row['F3'] != '#')):
    return str(row['F3'])
 elif (str(row['F4'] != '-') & str(row['F4'] != '#')):
    return str(row['F4'])
 else:
    return ''

 df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row : fill_values(row), axis=1)
```

I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'". Not sure what's going wrong in the above code. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so called *operator precedence*, you need to put your `()` in correct places:

```
if (str(row['F1']) != '-' & str(row['F1']) != '#'):
```

should be

```
if (str(row['F1']) != '-') & (str(row['F1']) != '#'):
                         ^   ^
                         these
```

That said, a better way to do is:

```
df['Result'] = df.replace('-', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: "#" needs to be replace too and ussage of replace will be messy when there will be more symbols to exclude.. so use regex instead..

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani  FYI, `replace` accepts list. Since OP is replacing the whole cell value, it's better with vanila `replace`, although `replace` has an option `regex=True`...

Comment: @MustafaAydın please re-read the fix. It is totally valid, as `()` wraps around a string comparison, yielding a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

- Get list of values against each row of only columns specified in variable named *mapping_columns*
- Use `list comprehension` to remove all values which are specified in variable named *not_consider* and then join that list to make a single string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"F1":["-","-","-","-"],"F2":["#1234","#5678","-","#78910"],"F3":["-","-","Unknown","-"],"F4":["-","-","#","-"]})

not_consider = ["-","#"]
mapping_columns = ["F1","F2","F3","F4"]

df["Result"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[mapping_columns].to_list(), axis = 1)
df["Result"] = df.Result.apply(lambda x: " ".join([i for i in x if not(i in not_consider) ]))

print(df)

       F1    F2        F3 F4   Result
    0  -   #1234        -  -    #1234
    1  -    5678        -  -    #5678
    2  -       -  Unknown  #  Unknown
    3  -  #78910        -  -   #78910
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
df1 = df1.replace(to_replace='-', value='')
df1 = df1.replace(to_replace='#', value='')
df['result'] = df1.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```